# Hamcrest matcher doesn't match although expected and actual are the same [Rest Assured]

Tags: java, api, get, rest-assured, hamcrest

I am new to Rest Assured and hamcrest matchers,

I wrote the following code below and I am wondering what went wrong, because I am getting assertion error despite expected and actual parameters being the same.

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class TC_GET {
 @Test
    public void test_02(){
        baseURI = "http://localhost:3000/";
        given()
                .param("name","DevOps")
                .get("subjects")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("id",equalTo("[2]"))
                .log().all();
    }
}
```

[image]

This is my db.json file

[image]

Also, if I create a new int[] {2} parameter instead of writing "[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIUcM.png)", such as
[image]

I have the following error

[image]

Is there anyone who can give me insight on this? Any help is appreciated.

Best,

Comment: Have you tried `body("id",equalTo(2))` ?

Comment: @GauthamM yes I tried but It gives me the following: java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path id doesn't match.
Expected: <2>
  Actual: [2]

Comment: Have you tried to debug inside the `equalTo` method?

Comment: @GauthamM I tried it but unfortunately I didn't understand what's going on in the source code of hamcrest matchers :/ This seems to be an issue in my opinion.. a weird one

Comment: Could you try if this is working : 
`given().param("id",2).get("subjects").then().statusCode(200).body("name",equalTo("DevOps")).log().all();`

Comment: @GauthamM Not working. Gives me the following : java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path name doesn't match.
Expected: DevOps
  Actual: [DevOps]

Comment: Did you try to include `.asserThat()` before the `.body()` ? `then().statusCode(200).assertThat().body("id",2)`

Comment: Yes and still [DevOps]. For some reason, matcher sees the Json values as array elements [like this]..

Comment: While debugging the `equalTo`, did you verify the type of the actual and expected data?